Filter results of the component based on the url
I am building a project with Next.js and Pocketbase and would like to understand the best practises for routing / passing propos in my case.

I am using Pocketbase to fetch data in a app/config.tsx file:

import PocketBase from 'pocketbase';

export async function getArtworks() {
    const pb = new PocketBase(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_POCKETBASE_URL);
    pb.autoCancellation(false);
    await pb.admins.authWithPassword(process.env.POCKETBASE_EMAIL, process.env.POCKETBASE_PASSWORD);
    const data = await pb.collection('artworks').getFullList({
        sort: '-created',
        cache: 'no-store',
    });

    return data.map((record) => {
        console.log(record)
        console.log(record.id, record.image)
        if (record.image) {
            const image = pb.files.getUrl(record, record.image);
            return {
                ...record,
                image,
            };
        } else {
            return record;
        }
    },
    )
}

export async function getInitialProps() {
    const artworks = await getArtworks();

    return {
        props: {
            artworks,
        },
        revalidate: 10,
    };
}


I am wrapping it up in app/components/Artworks.txt (this component is reused across page.tsx and then within particular routes for each category like /painting or /music):

import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';
import style from './artworks.module.css';
import { getArtworks } from '../config';
import { Poppins } from "next/font/google";

const poppins = Poppins({ weight: '400', subsets: ['latin'] });

export default async function Artwork() {
    const artworks = await getArtworks();
    const categories = artworks.map((artwork) => artwork.type)
    const unique_categories = [...new Set(categories)]

    return (
        <div>
            <div className={style.artwork__container}>
                {unique_categories.map((category) => (
                    <div className={style.category__container}>
                        <Link href={`${category.toLowerCase()}`}
                            className={`${style.category} ${poppins.className}`}>
                            <span>{category}</span>
                            <span>&rarr;</span>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}


Now based on the url (whether it is /music or /film etc.), I would like to display Artworks component but filtered by the category (music, film etc.). I did research, but with so many ways to approach it, it is more confusing that helpful.

